# How do I open a VM I received in VirtualBox?

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

A lady "put together a virtual machine" that was supposed to include a certain software and related packages. I was given a folder of files (vmdk, log, vmxf, plist, vmsd, nvram, and png files) and told to use VirtualBox. I honestly hardly know where to start. I downloaded virtual box. In the VirtualBox window that came up I clicked new.
I have tried two different things. First I tried to "use an existing virtual hard disk file" while creating my virtual machine. That didn't work, or maybe I just don't know how to make it work. 
Second I made my virtual machine by creating a virtual hard disk. Then I went into settings, selected storage, and tried to open the file. That didn't end up working. 
Am I even on the right track? Does anyone have any suggestions for doing this?

Comment: None of those files can be used natively with VirtualBox they are VMware files.

Answer (score 2):

These files are for a VMware virtual machine. While you might be able to get it to run with VirtualBox (with the method LPChip mentioned and some additional configuration), the emulated hardware won’t be exactly the same. This is especially true for storage controllers other than SATA.

However, if there’s no `.vmx` file, the main configuration is missing.

Answer (score 0):

After you have installed VirtualBox, just doubleclick the vdmk file to import that virtual machine.